# How to make a a:hover gradually have other colour

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

Hi,
My menu has the colour `#006699`, when hover I want it to **gradually**
go over to the colour `#4796E9`.
Is that possible?

Comment: There's no need for Javascript!!! Look at my answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com). CSS Tricks has a tutorial called *Color Fading Menu with jQuery* [here](http://css-tricks.com/color-fading-menu-with-jquery/).

Answer (score 8):

You can also achieve it with CSS3 (it will work on all browsers except IE9 and lower, though). Here is an example:

```
-webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
-ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
```

Comment: It's now 2017 and I think it's fair to say this is the only really good, acceptable, solution :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the sort of thing you could do using [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects).

Ben

Answer (score 1):

### You DO NOT NEED JavaScrip!!!

This can be easily accomplished with `CSS3 transitions`

```
<style>
nav {
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  background-color: #006699;
  color: white;
}

nav:hover {
  background-color: #4796E9;
}
</style>


<nav>
  <h1>This menu changes color GRADUALLY on mouse-hover</h1>
</nav>
```

Look at my working codepen: http://codepen.io/omarjuvera/pen/vGMezz

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible with CSS. But you can do it via javascript. Try the [fadeIn](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeIn#speedcallback) effect in jquery.

Comment: fadeIn() only affects opacity of an element, and is used to display elements otherwise hidden.

Comment: Mark, you're right that fadeIn would not be the right effect, but the point is that jquery will solve this problem. Thanks for the downgrade.

Comment: @notorious2tall Look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://davidwalsh.name/fading-links-jquery-dwfadinglinks) a plugin someone did with JQuery that does this.

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript ( you can do it easy with a jQuery animate() method) or WebKit CSS animations: http://webkit.org/blog/138/css-animation/ (note that this method only works in WebKit).

I recommend the JavaScript route -- using a framework like jQuery or scriptaculous.
Info on jQuery's animate method here: [http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate#paramsdurationeasingcallback)